# Существуют ли проблемы при возвращении Map<> в ApiController REST сервиса?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

В рабочем процессе мне сказали, что возвращение в качестве ответа веб-приложения Map<> недопустимо и нужно использовать типизированные ДТО.
Кто-то может подсказать, почему это так?

```
public Map<String, UUID> init(String someProperty) {
    HashMap<String, UUID> response = new HashMap<>();
    response.put("propertyId", doSomething(someProperty));

    return response;
}
```

Comment: DTO как минимум помогают отслеживать, где что используется. Для больших долгоиграющих проектов это важно. Ну и API specification по ДТО можно сгенерировать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сложно ответить, так как зависит от задачи и бизнес требований :))

Концептуально API это контракт и гарантии что сервер вернет вот такую структуру(DTO) а клиент ее обработает. Так же Map, в вашем примере, не расширяема, то есть если нужно будет добавить какое то еще поле в value, то придется делать либо новое api -> v2 либо UUID менять на ваш объект, либо править клиента.